# FEM Meshrefinement for 1D Interval and Elements of order 2

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I would like to create a 1D mesh of the intervall (-pi/2,pi/2) for solving a DE with FEM, with more elements close to +-1 - these elements should be of order 2, since order 1 elements yield too low accuracy.

For the function ToElementMesh the option "MeshRefinementFunction" does not work in 1D, which is why I tried to first use the function Discretize region and convert the result a FEM mesh, this gives the wrong answer though:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
A = ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}}];
f = Function[{vertices, area}, 
   area > 0.01 (1 + 10*Abs[(Norm[Mean[vertices]] - 1)])];
B = DiscretizeRegion[A, MeshRefinementFunction -> f]

Z = ToElementMesh[B]
ElementMesh[{{-1.5708, 4.63385}}, {LineElement["<" 159 ">"]}]
```

The resulting mesh goes from -pi/2 to ~4.6 and not to pi/2 as it should be. Is there any way to get this to work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, smells like a bug. You can use this in the mean time:

```
MeshOrderAlteration[B["MakeRepresentation"["ElementMesh"]], 2]
```

Comment: This gives me just what I needed, thanks a lot!